# Accessing a generator item when applying a map function

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

Say that I have a function:

```
def plus(x):
    return [x+1, x+2]
```

and some data where I'd like to apply the function above to:

```
 data=(i for i in range(5)) #large, don't fit in ram
```

I'm looping through the results of the map function. I'm trying to get the value of the data variable, when the results of the map function meet certain category:

```
for result in map(plus, data) or []:
     if result >3:
        print(f"{result} -xx")
```

how can I access generator item that is meeting this criteria (marked xx above)? one way i can think of is to append the variable x within the plus function back to the list being returned, but this seems redundant.

Comment: please provide output for the example you have given... that would make your question a lot clearer.

Comment: What about `for d, result in ((d, plus(d)) for d in data):` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `itertools.tee` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) makes stuff like this practical (and using it for parallel iteration is the only case where it actually saves memory, so this is the perfect case for it):

```
import itertools

# Make two iterators that will each produce the original data once
# When the value has been produced by one iterator, it is cached internally;
# when the second iterator produces it, it's discarded
data, data2 = itertools.tee(data)

# Iterate original data and mapped data in parallel
for x, result in zip(data, map(plus, data2)):
     if result >3:
        print(f"{result} {x}")
```

Note that I removed the `or []`, because it's guaranteed to be pointless; `map` objects are always truthy, so you'd always end up iterating the `map` object (which works just fine, even if it turns out to be empty).